# Java Programming - Spring and JDBCTemplate - Use query, queryForList or queryForRowSet?

Tags: java, spring, recordset, jdbctemplate

My Java (JDK6) project uses [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) and [JDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) for all its database access. We recently upgraded from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3 (RC1). The project does not use an ORM like [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) nor [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EJB).

If I need to read a bunch of records, and do some internal processing with them, it seems like there are several (overloaded) methods: query, queryForList and queryForRowSet

What should be the criteria to use one instead of the other? Are there any performance differences? Best practices?

Can you recommend some external references for further research on this topic?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I find that the standard way to access as list is via the `query()` methods rather than any of the other approaches.  The main difference between `query` and the other methods is that you'll have to implement one of the callback interfaces (either `RowMapper`, `RowCallbackHandler`, or `ResultSetExtractor`) to handle your result set.

A `RowMapper` is likely what you'll find yourself using most of the time.  It's used when each row of the result set corresponds to one object in your list.  You only have to implement a single method `mapRow` where you populate the type of object that goes in your row and return it.  Spring also has a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` which can populate the objects in a list via matching the bean property names to the column names (NB this class is for convenience not performance).

A `RowCallbackHandler` is more useful when you need your results to be more than just a simple list.  You'll have to manage the return object yourself you are using this approach.  I usually find myself using this when I need a map structure as my return type (i.e. for grouped data for a tree table or if I'm creating a custom cache based of the primary key).

A `ResultSetExtractor` is used when you want to control the iteration of the results.  You implment a single method `extractData` that will be the return value of the call to `query`.  I only find myself using this if I have to build some custom data structure that is more complex to build using either of the other callback interfaces.

The `queryForList()` methods are valuable in that you don't have to implement these callback methods.  There are two ways use queryForList.  The first is if you're only querying a single column from the database (for example a list of strings) you can use the versions of the method that takes a Class as an argument to automatically give you a list of only objects of those classes.

When calling the other implementations of `queryForList()` you'll get a list back with each entry being a map of  for each column.  While this is nice in that you are saved the expense of writing the callback methods, dealing with this data structure is quite unwieldy.  You'll find yourself doing a lot of casting since the map's values are of type `Object`.

I've actually never seen the `queryForRowSet` methods used in the wild.  This will load the entire result of the query into a `CachedRowSet` object wapped by a Spring SqlRowSet.  I see a big downside in using this object in that if you're passing the `SqlRowSet` around to the other layers of your application, you're coupling those layers to your data access implementation.

You shouldn't see any huge performance differences between any of these calls except as I mentioned with the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.  If you're working with some complex manipulation of a large result set, you might be able to get some performance gains from writing an optimized `ResultSetExtractor` for your specific case.

If you want to learn more I would consult the [Spring JDBC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) and the [JavaDoc for the classes I've mentioned](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/).  You can also take a look at some of the books on the Spring Framework.  Though it's a bit dated [Java Development with the Spring Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574833) has a very good section on working with the JDBC framework. Most of all, I would say just try writing some code with each method and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are in the wonderful Generics land, what you may really want to do is to use [`SimpleJdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html) and use its `query()` methods for `Lists` of objects and `queryForObject()` for individual objects. Reasoning for this simply is that they're even easier to use than the ones in `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: AFIK the Java 5 compliant query method is available in JDBCTemplate as well in Spring 3

Comment: Now that I checked, JdbcTemplate isn't using Generics in Spring 2.5.6 but it is in 3.0.0. I smell a deprecation in the future... :)

Comment: SimpleJdbcTemplate is now indeed deprecated

Comment: @Helenesh Such things tend to happen in seven and half years, yes. :)

Answer (score 3):

One small addition to the excellent answers above: additional methods, like queryForInt, queryForLong, queryForMap, queryForObject, etc. might seem like good options at times if you're running a simple query and expect a single row.

However, if you could get 0 or 1 rows back, the queryForList method is generally easier, otherwise you'd have to catch IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.  I learned that the hard way.

Comment: Hard way is the best way to learn. We will never forget that and it also helps a lot to others. So as a species we will save time somewhere. This is helping me after 15 years! Thanks for sharing. :)